# Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript

I struggle with a javascript error, that I cannot get rid of: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not an object.`

This is the script, that is used in a cookie consent module after the  tag:

```
window.addEventListener("load", setTimeout(   function(){
  window.cookieconsent.initialise({ 
  "palette": { "popup": {"background": "#DCDCDC"}, 
              "button": {"background": "#9bba44"}
              }, 
  "position": "bottom-right", 
  "content": { "message": "We use cookies.", 
               "accept": "Accept all", 
               "deny": "Decline all",
               "link": "Find out more." } 
  })
}, 3000));
</script>
```

If needed I can look into cookieconsent.initialise, but the error may be something else, more trivial to anyone with experience. 
What is the second parameter here?

Comment: This is a basic issue. Your `setTimeout` is not a *function* but a *function call*. Wrap it in yet another function.

Comment: Yes! That was it! Many thanks!

Comment: @wiktor-zychla This was quick. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of `window.addEventListener` should be a function.

What you have boils down to:

```
window.addEventListener("load", setTimeout(function(){ /* stuff */}, 3000));
```

That `setTimeout` is called the moment you call `addEventListener`, and the return value of `setTimeout` (The timeout `id`) is passed to `addEventListener`.

You need to wrap the `setTimeout` in a function:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => setTimeout(function(){
    /* stuff */
}, 3000));
```

Now, you're passing a function to `addEventListener` that can be called on the `load` event. That function will set a new timeout.

Comment: All I need now is to figure out how to construct the function at runtime.