# Why is this causing an uncaught type error

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with why this is throwing an `uncaught type error argument 2 is not an object`? I know it's in `window.addEventListener('load', fadeEffect);`
I'm busy learning JS so struggling to figure it out.

```
const preloader = document.querySelector('.preloader');

const fadeEffect = setInterval(() => {

    if (!preloader.style.opacity) {
        preloader.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (preloader.style.opacity > 0) {
        preloader.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
}, 100);

window.addEventListener('load', fadeEffect);
```

Comment: You're passing an interval in as the second argument, not a function.  Or whatever `setInteval` returns, which may just be a number referencing the interval.  *"The returned intervalID is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to setInterval(); this value can be passed to WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearInterval() to cancel the timeout."*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655266/failed-to-execute-addeventlistener-on-eventtarget  hope this helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655266/failed-to-execute-addeventlistener-on-eventtarget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `setInterval` is a number representing the ID value of the timer that is set.

And the second parameter on `window.addEventListener` should be function.

So you need to make `fadeEffect` as function as follows.

```js
const preloader = document.querySelector('.preloader');

const fadeEffect = () => setInterval(() => {

    if (!preloader.style.opacity) {
        preloader.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (preloader.style.opacity > 0) {
        preloader.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
}, 100);

window.addEventListener('load', fadeEffect);
```

```html
<div class="preloader">Preloader</div>
```